# How to select row index by column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `Dataframe` in python and trying to select row index based on multiple column values. Below is the 100th row's value of my dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc[100]
id                                       100
iid     9cdb7709-38f8-442a-812a-986b5b148161
lat                                 -37.8294
lon                                  144.979
name                      Doryanthes excelsa
Name: 100, dtype: object
```

I want to select the rows whose `id` is 100 and `lat` is -37.8294 by below command:

```
>>> df[(df['id'] == 100) & (df['lat'] == -37.8294)].index
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

the above command returns an empty index. I don't understand that I can get the value by `df.loc[100]` command but why can't I get the row index from the above command?

Comment: are all your dtypes consistent? is `'lat'` isn't a string or anthing like that? Your output would make me think that it is not finding anything that matches those conditions, and dtype inconsistencies is a common way for that to happen.

Comment: `print df['lat'].dtype` to check iirc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want select `float`, but there is precision problem, so get no match and return empty dataframe

So need [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
df1 = df[(df['id'] == 100) & (np.isclose(df['lat'],-37.8294))]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,200],
                   'lat':[-37.82940007,-37.82]})
print (df)
    id      lat
0  100 -37.8294
1  200 -37.8200

df1 = df[(df['id'] == 100) & (df['lat'] == -37.8294)]
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, lat]
Index: []

df1 = df[(df['id'] == 100) & (np.isclose(df['lat'],-37.8294))]
print (df1)
    id      lat
0  100 -37.8294
```

Comment: @Stael - Thank you

Comment: this is a good shout - I wouldn't have thought of this, but in this example is it actually the problem? With default display options pandas seems to show floats to 6dp, so it seems unlikely that this is a precision thing. I assumed he's got some strings in there by accident.

Comment: yes this solved my issue. It is a precision problem. I will accept the answer in 5 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhaoYi huh, what was the actual value for `'lat'` that produced that output then?

Comment: @Stael the output of that command prints an array of index not the value.

Comment: @ZhaoYi I know - but it does that by matching the float value of your `'lat'` column against the float `-37.8294` by my understanding of this there is a very limited set of values that would _display_ `-37.8294` and but not _match_ `-37.8294`. I wondered if you could tell me the actual value so i could confirm/refute my understanding.

Comment: @stael The `lat` value from my data set is `-37.8294`.